# Gmail API "Error 403: Request had insufficient authentication scopes" with Go language

Tags: go, gmail-api

Following the Go Quickstart instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/go) , enabled the Gmail API, downloaded the client configuration and then executed quickstart.go.  The following line shows the GmailSendScope is being requested.

```
config, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, gmail.GmailSendScope)
```

Followed the rest of the instructions. While saving the token.json, the program displayed following message:

```
Saving credential file to: token.json
2020/10/07 12:36:13 Unable to retrieve labels: googleapi: Error 403: Request had 
insufficient authentication scopes.
More details:
Reason: insufficientPermissions, Message: Insufficient Permission
```

On the developer console, I do see Oauth client of type Desktop for Quickstart project and the security screen did show that I am allowing application to send emails using my gmail account.

I am not sure how to fix this issue.

macOS Catalina 10.15.7,  go1.15.2 darwin/amd64

Thanks for help!!!

Comment: Can I ask you about the difference between your current script and [the script of quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/go)?

Comment: The only difference is the line I listed above. Original script has gmail.GmailReadonlyScope. The program worked with that scope. But I need to send emails so  changed scope to gmail.GmailSendScope and token.json file cannot be saved. I deleted the token.json file for ReadonlyScope before running the script for GmailSendScope as suggested in the script.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your case, when `gmail.MailGoogleComScope` is used instead of `gmail.GmailSendScope`, what result will you get? In this case, `gmail.MailGoogleComScope` is `https://mail.google.com/`. By the way, when you modified the scopes, please delete `token.json` and reauthorize the scopes again. Please be careful this.

Comment: Yes, that did it.  Thank you very much, I had spend lot of hours on this. The next step is to actually send an email. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Tanaike. Using `gmail.MailGoogleComScope` solved the issue!